# Python POST requests to a reload page

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have a web page where I fill two inputs then it reload with autofilled infos, and I have to input two more inputs then i can make the final POST.

The problem is if I make 2 POST requests it's like it erase the first one.

The url of the two post is the same maybe that's why. 
How can i post twice in the same url without clearing first one?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the first POST request that you are sending is having some data for the second one. In that case you cannot just send the request in simple way. You should try with **session**. You can find some tuts about it in [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.8.1/user/advanced/) of requests library or by searching some in google.

Comment: it's not working, second POST requests just overrides the first one. I guess because the POST url is the same. Even using cookies.